# Filter only particular format of date in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've a dataframe where some of the fields are having the date format of D.HH:mm:ss, D.HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS & HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS.  I'll need to filter only the date of type HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS and convert this date to seconds(integer).

I've written below scala code that converts the date to seconds. I need help in filtering the date type of a particular format(HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS) only and skip other formats of date in a dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 def hoursToSeconds(a: Any): Int = {
  val sec = a.toString.split('.')
  val fields = sec(0).split(':')
  val creationSeconds = fields(0).toInt*3600 + fields(1).toInt*60 + fields(2).toInt
  return creationSeconds
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task can be split up into two parts:

1. Filter the required rows with the help of [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@rlike(literal:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
2. calculate the seconds in an [udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html)

Create some test data:

```
val df = Seq(
   ("one", "1.09:39:26"),
   ("two", "1.09:39:26.1234567"),
   ("three", "09:39:26.1234567")
 ).toDF("info", "time")
```

Definition of regexp and udf:

```
val pattern = "\\A(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})\\.\\d{7}\\z".r

val toSeconds = udf{in: String => {
  val pattern(hour, minute, second) = in
  hour.toInt * 60 * 60 + minute.toInt * 60 + second.toInt
}}
```

The actual code:

```
df
  .filter('time rlike pattern.regex)
  .select('info, 'time, toSeconds('time).as("seconds"))
  .show
```

prints

```
+-----+----------------+-------+
| info|            time|seconds|
+-----+----------------+-------+
|three|09:39:26.1234567|  34766|
+-----+----------------+-------+
```

If the lines that do not have the correct format should be kept, the udf can be changed slightly and the filter has to be removed:

```
val pattern = "\\A(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})\\.\\d{7}\\z".r

val toSeconds = udf{in: String => {
  in match {
    case pattern(hour, minute, second)=> hour.toInt * 60 * 60 + minute.toInt * 60 + second.toInt
    case _ => 0
  }
}}

df
  .select('info, 'time, toSeconds('time).as("seconds"))
  .show
```

prints

```
+-----+------------------+-------+
| info|              time|seconds|
+-----+------------------+-------+
|  one|        1.09:39:26|      0|
|  two|1.09:39:26.1234567|      0|
|three|  09:39:26.1234567|  34766|
+-----+------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try matching using a regex with extractors like so:

```scala
val dateRegex = """(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{7})""".r

val D_HH_mm_ss = "1.12:12:12"
val D_HH_mm_ss_SSSSSSS = "1.12:12:12.1234567"
val HH_mm_ss_SSSSSSS = "12:12:12.1234567"

val dates = List(HH_mm_ss_SSSSSSS, D_HH_mm_ss_SSSSSSS, D_HH_mm_ss)

dates.foreach {
  _ match {
    case dateRegex(hh, mm, ss, sssssssss) => println(s"Yay! $hh-$mm-$ss")
    case _ => println("Nay :(")
  }
}
```